# what is the correct way to process 4 bits inside an octet in python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I'm writing an application to parse certain network packets. A packet field contains the protocol version number in an octet, so that 4 high bits are the 'major' and low 4 are the 'minor' version. Currently I am parsing them as follows, but am wondering if there is a prettier or more 'pythonic' way of doing it:

```
    v = ord(data[17])
    major = (v & int('11110000',2) ) >> 4
    minor = v & int('00001111',2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write binary literals like this`0b1111000`

For your example I would proabbly use hex though

```
v = ord(data[17])
major = (v & 0xF0) >> 4
minor = (v & 0x0F)
```

You might also want to use the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module to break the packet into its components

Comment: 0v11110000 does not work as I am stuck with 2.4 python, but using hex makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well named functions are always a good way to hide ugliness and irrelevant complexity. This way the bit-fiddling is confined to small and easily proven correct functions while the higher level code can refer to the purpose of the fiddling.

```
def high_nibble(byte):
    """Get 4 high order bits from a byte."""
    return (byte >> 4) & 0xF

def low_nibble(byte):
    """Get 4 low order bits from a byte."""
    return byte & 0xF

def parse_version(version_byte):
    """Get the major-minor version tuple from the version byte."""
    return high_nibble(version_byte), low_nibble(version_byte)

major, minor = parse_version(version_byte)
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be neater to use literals instead of calling `int`. You can use binary literals or hex, for example:

```
major = (v & 0xf0) >> 4
minor = (v & 0x0f)
```

Binary literals only work for Python 2.6 or later and are of the form `0b11110000`. If you are using Python 2.6 or later then you might want to look at the `bytearray` type as this will let you treat the data as binary and so not have to use the call to `ord`.

If you are parsing binary data and finding that you are having to do lots of bit wise manipulations then you might like to try a more general solution as there are some third-party module that specialise in this. One is hachoir (edit: removed invalid link 1/2023), and a lower level alternative is bitstring (edit: removed invalid link 1/2023) (which I wrote). In this your parsing would become something like:

```
major, minor = data.readlist('uint:4, uint:4')
```

which can be easier to manage if you're doing a lot of such reads.

Answer (score -1):

Just one hint, you'd better apply the mask for the major *after* shifting, in case it's a negative number and the sign is kept:

```
major = (v >> 4) & 0x0f
minor = (v & 0x0f)
```

Comment: Your syntax seems invalid, and I think ord will only ever return a positive number.

Comment: I'm glad to see that you're good spotting typos... when playing with bitmasks it's better to make sure that your code is robust against eventualities like an interface change (I'm not expecting ord to change, but it's not unlikely that this snippet could be refactored and having a bug caused by a sign expansion while shifting left is harder to spot than an invalid syntax)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see when `(v >> 4) & 0x0f` will ever be different to `(v & 0xf0) >> 4` (can you give an example?). In some languages shifting left (rather than right) might cause a top bit to be set which could change the sign, but that's not going to happen with integers in Python.

Comment: I meant shift _right_... I'm not paying much attention. It's true that in Python that is less prone to happen (as it automatically upcasts to longints and crops the sign), but it's still a good practice to mask after shifting to keep the code meaningful in other languages, and in case of interfacing with C via CTypes, for example...